# Why do ICMP packets > 71 bytes timeout?

Tags: networking, windows-10, ping

On my parents' network I noticed that ICMP packets larger than 71 bytes do not go though.

- `ping 1.1.1.1 -l 71` (and below) is fine
- `ping 1.1.1.1 -l 72` (and above) fail with `Request timed out`

I tested this on two different Windows 10 computers, one of them is wired to the router (a TP-LINK Archer C50) and another one is connected via Wi-Fi. In both cases  the threshold packet size is the same.

**What can be the reason for that?**

Firewalls on both computers are disabled, and the Archer C50 firewall is enabled with default settings (which I do not see being configurable). I tried with the firewall ("Stateful Packet Inspection" as they call it) enabled and disabled - same thing.

I also had a look at how Wireshark sees the `icmp` traffic - I only see ping requests.

EDIT: this happens starting from the IP of my gateway (= the fist IP after my router). Pinging either my computer or my router is OK.

Comment: What happens if you ping the private IP address of your router? What happens if you ping the first hop address on the ISP's end of your broadband link?

Comment: @Spiff: I updated the question with your remark. This behaviour starts at the IP of the gateway (my computer and my router are OK)